# "Unexpected end of JSON input" Error When Using Environment Variable in NodeJS/Express MySQL connection for User and Password

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, express, environment-variables

I am working on a React app with NodeJS/Express and MySQL. I was able to establish a database connection with everything working properly until I try to use environment variables for the user, password, and database in the database connection. The relevant backend code is

```
    const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_USER,
    password: process.env.REACT_APP_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.REACT_APP_DB,
    port: 3306,
});
```

I have a feeling I'm using these env variables incorrectly because my Jason Web Token secret is not being recognized either but I'm confused because the "host" in the code above works with the env variable. My .env file looks like this with the *'s being plain text

```
REACT_APP_DB_HOST=localhost
REACT_APP_DB_USER=****
REACT_APP_DB_PASS=************
REACT_APP_DB=************
REACT_APP_DB_PORT=3306
REACT_APP_JWT_SECRET=*********
```

If it matters, when the page loads the app makes an async await request to an api endpoint and the query in the backend gets the 15 latest rows in the database then basically displays the latest entries on the home screen.

```
const getRequest = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/api/get/`);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }



app.get('/api/get/', (req, res)=> {
    
    const sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
    db.query(sqlSelect, (err, result) => {
        res.send(result);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the dotenv dependency was absent for some reason from my package.json. I may have forgotten to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to load environment variable with :

require('dotenv').config()